# Initialised property in class instance is "undefined" if set to zero or an empty string

Tags: angular, typescript

I have an instance of a class, in which several number and string properties are initialized to 0 or "" respectively. When accessing these properties they are "undefined". Initializing these properties to anything else, ie 0.1 or " " and it is considered defined.

Why? Are 0 and "" equivalent to undefined?

```js
export class Car {
     id = 0
     name = ""
}
```

If I have an instance of Car and try to access a property it will be "undefined",

```js
let myCar = new Car
if (myCar.id) {
    console.log('yay')
} else {
    console.log('boo')
}
```

It will show 'boo'.

Comment: 0 and empty string are default values for those types respectively and will evaluate to false. change `if(myCar.id)` to `if(myCar.id !== undefined)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In javascript, the value `0` is evaluated as a falsy statement. Same for an empty string `""`. If you want to test if the property is undefined you need to do so explicitely

```
let myCar = new Car
if (myCar.id !== undefined) {
    console.log('yay')
} else {
    console.log('boo')
}
```